# Where should Guava EventBus Register Listeners

Tags: java, guava

I am currently having some issues using the Guava EventBus where events being posted are ending up in the DeadEvents for some reason, while others work fine. I suspect it has something to do with the order or location of where classes are being registered with the EventBus.

The EventBus is defined as a bean in my SpringContext

```
<bean class="com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus" id="eventBus" />
```

I'm using injecting that bean in three classes at present, and two of the classes are intended to send and receive events from each other, while the third class only post events.

Each class is calling

```
this.eventBus.register(this);
```

Does all the registeration need to take place in single location?

Comment: which of your events end up dead? Specific ones or random? Are you sure you have onle one bus instance?

Comment: Specific ones, and the bean is managed by Spring as a singleton so it is the only instance. I don't instantiate, only inject from SpringConext

Comment: Injection occurs on demand in Spring (so far as I understand the framework, it's been a while since I used it). If the constructors where the registrations occur don't get triggered until some later event occurs, then earlier events won't see all the registrations having occurred.

Also, it's possible multithreading change visibility effects are playing a part. Changes made to the eventbus singleton on one thread may take some unpredictable amount of time to become visible on other threads, unless you take specific steps to assure synchronization.